# Best way to implement Listview with the following items

Tags: flutter

I hope everyone are good,

[I have the following data structure in Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z59X.png)

i want the best way to use these items in widgets

i tried the following code but unfortunately its only display one item from the array
i am using List View builder, when i debugged the code i find that my array size only 1 i want a way to display the user_image array

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final messageProivder = Provider.of<MessageProvider>(context);
return Stack(children: [
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment:
        isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isMe ? Colors.grey[300] : Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
              topRight: Radius.circular(12),
              bottomLeft: !isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(12),
              bottomRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(12)),
        ),
        width: 200,
        height: 400,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder(
                future: messageProivder.getImages(),
                // ignore: missing_return
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Text('......');
                  }
                  final docs = snapshot;
                  String images;

                  Map<int, DocumentSnapshot> x = snapshot.data;
                  x.forEach((key, value) {
                    images = value['user_image'].toString();
                  });
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: x.length,
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, int index) {
                          int counter = 0;
                          int key = x.keys.elementAt(index);

                          return Container(
                            height: 200,
                            child: ListTile(title: getImageWidget(images)),
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                }),
            Text(
              message,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: isMe
                      ? Colors.black
                      : Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1.color),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
]);
```

}
}

```
Widget getImageWidget(String x) {
String temp = x.substring(1, x.length - 1);
temp.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"), "");
List<String> strings = temp.split(',');
List<Widget> images = List<Widget>();
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  images.add(Image.network(
    strings[i],
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
  ));
}
return Column(children: images);
```

}

[and here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzFUe.png)

Any answer could help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you want to display a list of images or a list of messages?

Comment: @AlpeshRathod both

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug here. I assume you want x in `getImageWidget(String x)` to be in the form of String 'image1Url,image2Url,image3Url,...'

So there is a bug in the code here at

```
String images;

Map<int, DocumentSnapshot> x = snapshot.data;
x.forEach((key, value) {
    images = value['user_image'].toString();
});
```

Change to

```
Map<int, DocumentSnapshot> x = snapshot.data;
x.forEach((key, value) {
    images += value['user_image'].toString() + ',';
});
```

Then the Widget will be

```
Widget getImageWidget(String x) {
 String temp = x.substring(0, x.length - 1);
 temp.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"), "");
 List<String> strings = temp.split(',');
 List<Widget> images = List<Widget>();
 for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
   images.add(Image.network(
     strings[i],
     height: 40,
     width: 40,
   ));
}
return Column(children: images);
```

Comment: Actuality the string have the all URLs btw thx for the answer